# Oracle SQL Query to mimic VLOOKUP functionality

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, vlookup

I'm trying to get VLOOKUP functionality within my Oracle SQL query. I have tried this by using a sub query select statement in there but it isn't returning any values.

**Required Logic**

The VLOOKUP logic is required in the `Lookup_Link_Date` field and then that is also used in the `Same_Date` fields.

Basically in Excel the `Lookup_Link_Date` field looks for the `Link_String` field in the `String` field and then returns the `date` that is next to it.

To try and replicate this in Oracle SQl I created a sub query select statement that looks for a `date` where the `type = type_ref AND no = no_ref` but its never returning any results and i'm not sure why.

**Current Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
g.type AS Type, 
g.no AS Number,
g.date AS Date, 
g.type_ref AS Type_Ref,
g.no_ref AS No_Ref, 
g.type||g.no||g.company AS String,
g.type_ref||g.no_ref||g.company AS Link_String,
(SELECT g.date 
 FROM gtable g 
 WHERE g.type_ref = g.type 
 AND g.no_ref = g.no) AS Lookup_Link_Date,
CASE WHEN (SELECT g.date 
           FROM gtable g 
           WHERE g.type_ref = g.type 
           AND g.no_ref = g.no) = g.date 
     THEN 'YES' 
     ELSE 'NO' 
     END AS Same_Date

FROM gtable g
```

**Attempt #2 Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
g.type AS Type, 
g.no AS Number,
g.date AS Date, 
g.type_ref AS Type_Ref,
g.no_ref AS No_Ref, 
g.type||g.no||g.company AS String,
g.type_ref||g.no_ref||g.company AS Link_String,
(SELECT b.date 
 FROM gtable b 
 WHERE b.type_ref = b.type 
 AND b.no_ref = b.no) AS Lookup_Link_Date,
CASE WHEN (SELECT d.date 
           FROM gtable d 
           WHERE d.type_ref = d.type 
           AND d.no_ref = g.no) = d.date 
     THEN 'YES' 
     ELSE 'NO' 
     END AS Same_Date

FROM gtable g
```

### **Attempt #3 WORKING Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
g.type AS Type, 
g.no AS Number,
g.date AS Date, 
g.type_ref AS Type_Ref,
g.no_ref AS No_Ref, 
g.type||g.no||g.company AS String,
g.type_ref||g.no_ref||g.company AS Link_String,
(SELECT date 
 FROM gtable 
 WHERE type_ref = g.type 
 AND no_ref = g.no) AS Lookup_Link_Date,
CASE WHEN (SELECT date 
           FROM gtable 
           WHERE type_ref = g.type 
           AND no_ref = g.no) = g.date 
     THEN 'YES' 
     ELSE 'NO' 
     END AS Same_Date

FROM gtable g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your aliases. It's g both inside and outside. Thus `g.type_ref = g.type` and `g.no_ref = g.no` supposedly don't compare what you want them to compare.

EDIT from Matt: Here is the query Matt got to work for him:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
g.type AS Type, 
g.no AS Number,
g.date AS Date, 
g.type_ref AS Type_Ref,
g.no_ref AS No_Ref, 
g.type||g.no||g.company AS String,
g.type_ref||g.no_ref||g.company AS Link_String,
(SELECT date 
 FROM gtable 
 WHERE type_ref = g.type 
 AND no_ref = g.no) AS Lookup_Link_Date,
CASE WHEN (SELECT date 
           FROM gtable 
           WHERE type_ref = g.type 
           AND no_ref = g.no) = g.date 
     THEN 'YES' 
     ELSE 'NO' 
     END AS Same_Date
FROM gtable g;
```

EDIT (after acceptance :-) Here is how to write the query with a self join:

```
SELECT 
  g.type AS Type, 
  g.no AS Number,
  g.date AS Date, 
  g.type_ref AS Type_Ref,
  g.no_ref AS No_Ref, 
  g.type||g.no||g.company AS String,
  g.type_ref||g.no_ref||g.company AS Link_String,
  gref.date AS Lookup_Link_Date,
  CASE WHEN g.date = gref.date THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Same_Date
FROM gtable g
LEFT JOIN gtable gref ON g.type = gref.type_ref and g.no = gref.no_ref;
```

(I removed DISTINCT. Are there duplicates? Then you need it, otherwise not.)

Comment: Change them or remove them completely?

Comment: Change them of course. One alias per table, so the dbms knows what record's column you mean. (E.g. `g1.type_ref = g2.type`).

Comment: Still no luck :(  Check Attempt #2 Query in Question for what i tried

Comment: I see `b.type_ref = b.type`, so you are looking for a record where type_ref equals type. This is certainly not what you want. You either want its type_ref to equal g.type or its type to equal g.type_ref, I don't know which. So far your inner query has nothing to do with the main query.

Comment: So try `(SELECT b.date 
 FROM gtable b 
 WHERE b.type_ref = g.type 
 AND b.no_ref = g.no) AS Lookup_Link_Date,` ?

Comment: This may be what you want, I don't know. You show all records from the table you call g. A record in g has a type and a no that points to exactly one record in the table (which you call b now) where b's type_ref equals g's type and b's no_ref equals g's no. Maybe it's this and maybe it's vice versa. Only you know.

Comment: Worked :)  ran out of upvotes today but i will tomorrow ! Thanks

Comment: And just a side note: Rather than doing the same sub-query twice, you would usually simply self join the table: `FROM gtable g LEFT JOIN gtable gref ON g.type = gref.type_ref and g.no = gref.no_ref`.

Comment: What are the advantages of this?

Comment: 1. A more readable query. 2. A faster query (because you don't do the same thing twice). Well, I'll edit my answer, so you see the full query.

Comment: thanks, ive added the working query to your answer already but feel free to edit it with th join rather than the sub query

Comment: Just in case you are still waiting for the join query :-) That's long done. I edited immediately after my last comment and right before your last reply.